# Load Balanced WP with single server admin access

Tags: wp-admin

I am trying to complete my load-balanced installation of WP and I have come into an issue. I would like to sync the uploads folder between the two installs but I do not know how to limit wp-admin access to a single server.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to provide more details about your setup, i.e. how you are doing the load balancing.

Answer (score 4):

I work on a Load balanced instance of WordPress where all uploaded content is stored on a separate server and each WordPress server's upload or blogs.dir folder is linked to that content server (a shared disk).

Out of the box I do not believe there is way to force Wordpress to use a single server.  You could try some host file magic and force the admin to use HTTPS and then limit all SSL connections to that server, but I would not recommend this solution.

If you need more help, you will need to provide more information about your set up as scribu mentioned.