# Will WP work on a multi-server environment?

Tags: multisite, hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Load Balanced WP with single server admin access](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6542/load-balanced-wp-with-single-server-admin-access)

I am planning to install wordpress in a multi-server environment.

2 load balancers/front end servers with a database server. Using CDN for all gallery uploads.

any ideas if this is going to work?

Is there any tutorial or article explaining this process?

Comment: The answer you got to your previous question on this (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6542/load-balanced-wp-with-single-server-admin-access) is still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

As long as they both respond to the same domain, you shouldn't have any problems with it at all.